# Microfocus ALM OCTANE REST API - Get existing manual test's step details

Tags: octane-sdk

I am trying to get existing manual test steps from ALM using the below REST API

https://almoctane-apj.saas.microfocus.com/api/shared_spaces/shared_space_id/workspaces/workspace_id/tests/manual_test_id/script

but I get the following result.

```
{
    "creation_time": "2020-01-16T14:36:52Z",
    "test_version": "{\"id\":1035,\"type\":\"test_version\"}",
    "version_stamp": 5,
    "last_modified": "2020-01-17T09:38:20Z",
    "script": "- Open Browser\n- Type Username\n- Type PAssword\n- Submit\n- @2012 Call <ReqTest1>\n- Login using <Username> and <Password>\n- ?isLoginSuccesfull"
}
```

Is there a way to get existing manual test steps with details(like id, description, etc) through REST API?

Answer (score 0):

i know that is six month late , but you could try calling entity test

http://URLdirection:PORT/api/shared_spaces//workspaces//tests?fields=id,latest_version&query=%22(id%3D%27yourTestId%27)%22

and once you have latest version you can call entity test_versions with attribute last_version that you got in the last request

http://URLdirection:PORT/api/shared_spaces//workspaces//test_versions?fields=id,script&query=%22(id%3D%27yourVersionID%27)%22

### and there you will get the steps , also you have to consider that before doing this you need to have stablished connection (requested cookies, etc...) for avoiding 403 error and properly setted headers and parameters for the request. and if you're using microfocus library i didn't find any direct call for test_versions entity

EDIT: also you can request to  http://URLdirection:PORT/api/shared_spaces//workspaces//test//script